# Storing pointers owned by auto_ptr's in a vector causing a crash

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, auto-ptr

I am having difficulty with a crash using an auto_ptr.  I am aware that you cannot store auto_ptr's in STL containers.  But what about storing pointer values held by the auto_ptr inside a vector?  If the auto_ptr's delete the stored object they point to, a subsequent destruction of a vector that stored these internal pointers causes my program to crash in the vectors Tidy_ method.

```
ClassA {
public:
   ClassA() {
      auto_pointer_1_.reset(new ClassP());
      auto_pointer_2_.reset(new ClassP());
      auto_pointer_3_.reset(new ClassP());
   };

   std::auto_ptr<ClassP> auto_pointer_1_;
   std::auto_ptr<ClassP> auto_pointer_2_;
   std::auto_ptr<ClassP> auto_pointer_3_;

};

ClassB {  
public: 
   ClassB(ClassA& a_class_a_) {
      vector_of_pointers_.push_back(a_class_a_.auto_pointer_1_.get());
      vector_of_pointers_.push_back(a_class_a_.auto_pointer_2_.get());
      vector_of_pointers_.push_back(a_class_a_.auto_pointer_3_.get());
   };

   std::vector<ClassP*> vector_of_pointers_;
};

void main(void) {

   ClassA* class_a_variable_ = new ClassA();

   ClassB* class_b_variable_ = new ClassB(*class_a_variable_);

   delete class_a_variable_;
   delete class_b_variable_;  <--- CRASH in std::vector Tidy_ method
}
```

Can anyone explain to me why the crash occurs?  When the auto_ptr deletes its stored pointer, the associated pointer in the vector is no longer pointing to anything but why would that prevent the vector from properly destructing?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/using_auto_ptr_effectively.htm

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't answer my question.

Comment: What does `ClassP` do?

Comment: Lets assume that ClassP does nothing.

Comment: Can you move to `std::unique_ptr`, or `std::tr1::unique_ptr`?  `auto_ptr` is BAD.

Comment: @Hans: That advice is 14 years old, and missing a lot of lessons learned since.  Today the advice for effective use of `auto_ptr` is much simpler: **Don't.**

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to support older compilers that do not include unique_ptr or tr1. And using boost is a no-go as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown there is no problem with the program when a stub `ClassP` is added that does nothing (and `class` is added where required, and `main()` changed to return `int`). The behavior you observe may be due to a corruption of the memory.

If any or all of `ClassA`, `ClassB` or `ClassP` actually have non-trivial destructors, it is possible that at least one of their destructor implementations has a bug that is causing undefined behavior. You should focus your attention on that.

Realize that `std::auto_ptr` has been deprecated, and you should use `std::unique_ptr` instead, as noted by Ben Voigt.

Comment: I believe you are correct.  This is a simplified example of a much larger implementation.  Thank you for your efforts and help.  I will focus my attention on what ClassP is doing when destructed.

Comment: I understand that auto_ptr is deprecated and would rather use unique_ptr (I actually started out with unique_ptr) but realized I have to support older compilers that do not include unique_ptr or tr1. And using boost is a no-go as well.

Comment: A future version of C++ may remove `auto_ptr` altogether, so you might want to use a `typedef` and an `#ifdef` that selects what kind of smart pointer you use.